# MongoDB aggregate allowDiskUse not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation

I am trying to allowDiskUse but that won't work either and still get a warning `aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16mb)`

I tried this but would throw the same warning again. What could be the reason?
Is it that it will throw the warning but fetch the results or it will fail to fetch the results?

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(...).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854932/spring-data-mongodb-and-allowdiskuse
Basically you have to add a batch size.

Comment: Thanks, @AntonNovopashin that helped!!

Comment: Mark as answered